# ManyToOne in Symfony2 + Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to create a relation betwen 4 tables.

- page (table for pages, fields: name, uri, status)
- block (table for blocks, here i can have multipy records for specific page, fields: id, parrent_id, template)
- block_content (table for contents of each block, here can have mulitpay records for a specific block, fields: id, block_id, lang, content)
- block_relation (holding relations betwen page table and block table, fields: id, page_id, block_id)

How can i create relations betwen those tables.

Till now i've created this:

**block_content:**

```
    <?php

namespace Casewise\Bundle\DispatcherBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * BlockRelation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="block_relation")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BlockRelation
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Casewise\Bundle\PageBundle\Entity\Page", inversedBy="block_relation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="page_id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    private $pageid;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Casewise\Bundle\CmsBundle\Entity\Block", inversedBy="block_relation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="block_id", referencedColumnName="block_id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    private $blockid;



    /** SETTERS AND GETTERS */



    /**
     * Gets the value of id.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of id.
     *
     * @param integer $id the id 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of pageid.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getPageid()
    {
        return $this->pageid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of pageid.
     *
     * @param integer $pageid the pageid 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setPageid($pageid)
    {
        $this->pageid = $pageid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of blockid.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBlockid()
    {
        return $this->blockid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of blockid.
     *
     * @param integer $blockid the blockid 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setBlockid($blockid)
    {
        $this->blockid = $blockid;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**block:**

```
namespace Casewise\Bundle\CmsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Block
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="block")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Block
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="block_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $blockid;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="parrent_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $parrentid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="template", type="string", length=150)
     */
    private $template;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean", options={"default" = 1})
     */
    private $status;



    /** SETTERS AND GETTERS */



    /**
     * Gets the value of blockid.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBlockid()
    {
        return $this->blockid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of blockid.
     *
     * @param integer $blockid the blockid 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setBlockid($blockid)
    {
        $this->blockid = $blockid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of parrentid.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getParrentid()
    {
        return $this->parrentid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of parrentid.
     *
     * @param integer $parrentid the parrentid 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setParrentid($parrentid)
    {
        $this->parrentid = $parrentid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of template.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTemplate()
    {
        return $this->template;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of template.
     *
     * @param string $template the template 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setTemplate($template)
    {
        $this->template = $template;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of status.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of status.
     *
     * @param string $status the status 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**BlockContent:**

```
    <?php

   namespace Casewise\Bundle\CmsBundle\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Block
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="block_content")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BlockContent
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Casewise\Bundle\CmsBundle\Entity\Block", inversedBy="block_id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="block_id", referencedColumnName="block_id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    private $blockid;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="language", type="string", length=15)
     */
    private $language;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;



    /** SETTERS AND GETTERS */



    /**
     * Gets the value of id.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of id.
     *
     * @param integer $id the id 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of blockid.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBlockid()
    {
        return $this->blockid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of blockid.
     *
     * @param integer $blockid the blockid 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setBlockid($blockid)
    {
        $this->blockid = $blockid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of name.
     *
     * @param string $name the name 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of language.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of language.
     *
     * @param string $language the language 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setLanguage($language)
    {
        $this->language = $language;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of content.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of content.
     *
     * @param string $content the content 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<?php

namespace Casewise\Bundle\PageBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Page
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="page")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="page_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $pageid;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uri", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $uri;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean", options={"default" = 1})
     */
    private $status;



    /** SETTERS AND GETTERS */



    /**
     * Gets the value of id.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getPageId()
    {
        return $this->pageid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of id.
     *
     * @param integer $id the id 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setPageId($pageid)
    {
        $this->pageid = $pageid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of name.
     *
     * @param string $name the name 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of uri.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUri()
    {
        return $this->uri;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of uri.
     *
     * @param string $uri the uri 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setUri($uri)
    {
        $this->uri = $uri;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of status.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of status.
     *
     * @param string $status the status 
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've update shema with: doctrine:schema:update --force
And when i request the Relation Entity and give him the pageid i need to get all related blocks to the specifc page, but it returns an **huge** object in which contains symfony2 specific objects(object with over 3000 lines), like requests, response and other objects which are not related to my request.

**This is how i request entity:**

```
$blocks = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('CasewiseDispatcherBundle:BlockRelation')
    ->findByPageid(1);
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r($blocks);
        echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can you precise your question ? What is your problem ? Moreover, with Symfony2 and Doctrine you don’t work with tables but with objects. It’s very different. Keep that in mind.

Comment: As I said, you’re not dealing with tables anymore. You’re dealing with objects. Then, creating an object "BlockRelation" makes no sense. Same for $pageid or $blockid. You should check the Symfony documentation to see how it works and how works an ORM. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations